# Would adding a new HDD make my computer slow?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm looking to understand whether adding a new 1TB HDD would make my computer slow. My specs are as follows:

- 500GB Seagate ST3500418AS SATA Core 2
- Duo E8200 @ 2.66GHz
- 2GB RAM DDR2 333MHz

If yes, would adding two new RAM modules of 2GB each (@ 800MHz) make it better? I'm just looking for personal experiences/linked articles, anything which would illuminate me.

Comment: The Mhz have to match. Tbh if you're asking this sort of question, you're more likely to have a virus. Get Microsoft Security Essentials if you don't already and do a scan.

Comment: @tobylane: My current system isn't slow and I think that with a software f/w + anti-virus suite I'm good as of now. Just wanted to know whether having a new HDD might slow the way I do my daily chores. Also, regarding the RAM, I'm thinking of discarding the current 2 GB one and get two new sticks. :)

Comment: Do you want to *add* another HDD, or *replace* the one you have?

Comment: @Daniel: I would like to add a new HDD to my system.

Comment: @sasuke: In that case, JamesT is right. The disk alone will not slow your machine down, only the countless files you can use that disk for (e.g. through desktop search indexing processes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't slow your system down. It won't increase the demand on the RAM or the CPU. it may take longer to navigate your folders but that is solved with good organisation.

Even if it would slow your system down 6GB RAM is a bit excessive.

When choosing a new hard drive, make sure the only difference between it and your primary one is the size of the storage.

Comment: I'll be discarding the current RAM stick so it'll be 4 GB total. Also, why do you say the speed (I assume RPM) has to be the same? Anything which proves not having them same would cause problems? Thanks.

Comment: the RPM has to be the same. The power rating needs to be in the range of your PSU so its safer to get one with the same or similar prower rating.

Comment: Thanks for the help, marking this as an accepted answer. Off to buy a new HDD. :-)